# Pausing MediaPlayer in a service from an activity

Tags: android

This is probably a newbie question, but how can I pause and resume my media player in a service from my activity. Here is what I have set up so far, but it is not working.

```
pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyService.pauseSong();
        }
    });
```

In my service is this:

```
public void pauseSong(){       
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() == true){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        notificationManagerPlay.cancel(5);
        pauseplay = 0;
    }
}
```

Your help is appreciated so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a wrapper static singelton class for MediaPlayer and you can access it from anywhere.

For an example you can look here: [Creating sound effects in android](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html)

As for singleton - [Singleton wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: Can you explain how to do this, or at least link to an example please?